# Vue SFC import TypeScript file throws "An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension." in VS Code

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am trying to change my `.vue` components to work with TypeScript instead of JavaScript.
For this reason my single file components look like this:

```
<template>
  ...something...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {  } from "./main.ts";

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My editor tells me that I cannot import files with extensions, so `"./main.ts"` appears to be an error even if I can succesfully build it running `webpack`.

If I remove the `.ts` extension, my editor works fine (it also detects the module exports) but webpack fails to build the dist file throwing this error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './main' in ...`.

[image: Visual Studio Code works fine]

My webpack config file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    plugins: [ new VueLoaderPlugin() ],
    module: {
            rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue']
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my configuration? Is it a problem of my editor or is it about the webpack configuration? How can I manage to let it work correctly?
Thanks

**Edit**:
After Jeff's answer (thanks Jeff), I changed the `extensions` and `alias` properties of my webpack configuration:

```
extensions: [ ".ts", ".js", ".vue" ],
alias: {
    "vue$": "vue/dist/vue.esm.js"
}
```

but this did not change the result.

[Here is a link to the source code](https://github.com/Pastello/Kathara-SDN-Interface/tree/stepbystep-webpack).

Answer (score 1):

Your Typescript imports typically should not end in extensions. Instead, Webpack should be configured to append the extensions as needed.

As in the [Microsoft Typescript Vue SFC example on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L46), your "resolve.extensions" list should include `.ts`:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
```

As in the `resolve.extensions` documentation:

> Attempt to resolve these extensions in order.
>
> > *If multiple files share the same name but have different extensions, webpack will resolve the one with the extension listed first in the array and skip the rest.*